# Possible meaning of "PR" abbreviation

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, abbreviations

I already know that PR can mean Public Relations or Puerto Rico, but none of these definition works in my context. I was on github, and an author basically said :

> If you like this plugin and want to say thanks please send a PR or donation. Both are equally appreciated!

[(Source)](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin)

In this context, **what does PR stand for ?**

Comment: Still an English learner, feel free to correct my grammar. But please, do not correct the quote in yellow. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess PR stands for "Pull Request" (you can see a tab for pull requests at the top of the page). That is, he'd like other people to try and contribute to his project.

Comment: That would make sense. Do you know if it's common to say PR in Github ?

Comment: I don't use github all that much, so I don't know how common it is. I've never really seen it in my (admittedly limited) experience.

Comment: Pull Requests are a common thing in distributed version control, haven't seen it abbreviated much though.

Comment: The abbreviation is very common on github and among any git-using open-source community.